# Form submits <select> as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following `<select>` inside a `<form>` that is submitted with ajax. The select is submitting with a value of: Undefined. What is wrong?

```
<select class="form-control" name="site_theme" id="site_theme" value="<?php $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM settings"); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['site_theme']; }?>">
   <?php 
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM themes");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo "<option VALUE='".$row['theme_name']."'>".$row['theme_name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
</select>
```

The javascript copied here to ugly to post so I made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yz5r4/

Also the above code results as:

```
<select class="form-control" name="site_theme" id="site_theme" value="Amelia">
   <option value="Amelia">Amelia</option>
   <option value="Cerulean">Cerulean</option>
   <option value="Cosmo">Cosmo</option>
   <option value="Cyborg">Cyborg</option>
   <option value="Flatly">Flatly</option>
   <option value="Journal">Journal</option>
   <option value="Readable">Readable</option>
   <option value="Simplex">Simplex</option>
   <option value="Slate">Slate</option>
   <option value="Spacelab">Spacelab</option>
   <option value="United">United</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show us your JavaScript,please!

Comment: You need to show your code.  How are you submitting the form?  What does the Javascript look like?

Comment: what is the HTML output of that page?

Comment: For one thing, you have double quotes inside a double-quoted echo in `".$row['theme_name']."` try using single quotes as in `'.$row['theme_name'].'` or mix `'".$row['theme_name']."'`

Comment: man the problem is in return false before AJAX call. When you put return the rest of the codes in that function would no be executed. try this http://jsfiddle.net/yz5r4/2/

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I don't think that relates to the problem.

Comment: All Great ideas and I have implemented everything, although I am still receiving an undefined.

Comment: @MitchEvans Try adding `[]` as in `name="site_theme[]"` since you are dealing with rows/arrays.

Comment: Check your code whether there exists any other element with the same ID `site_theme`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't change anything

Comment: @SuryaS Nothing else exists with the same id

Comment: what you mean than I get an undefined where you get that?

Comment: Do you load the `<select>` in to the page by an AJAX response?

Comment: do you mean you get an alert saying undefined? if yes try to alert each name theme and email separately.

Comment: @imsiso If you look in the JavaScript in the Fiddle, you will see that I am currently alerting the dataString out: `alert(dataString);` When that alert appears, I am getting this: `name=SaleLine&theme=undefined&email=moevans@green-panda.com`

Comment: When I echo them out by them selves I still receive `undefined` when I alert out theme

Comment: so when you get an undefined?

Comment: IN THE ALERT `&THEME=UNDEFINED`

Comment: ok I got it please w8

Comment: Is the `<select>` is loaded in to the page by PHP on loading the page or using an AJAX?

Comment: @SuryaS - the `<select>` is loaded in the html not by php or ajax. Does it need to be placed in the php?

Comment: @MitchEvans: No, but if it was loaded using AJAX you must call the function again.

Comment: I put the `<select>` in the php for making the options. Still nothing.

Comment: everybody please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you problems was first a return before ajax call.

second wrong selector for select!

Here is a sample that shows you. http://jsfiddle.net/yz5r4/3/

your selector : `$('input$("#site_theme")')`

but it should be `$("#site_theme")` or `$("select#site_theme")`

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="site_theme" id="site_theme" value="Amelia">
   <option value="Amelia">Amelia</option>
   <option value="Cerulean">Cerulean</option>
   <option value="Cosmo">Cosmo</option>
   <option value="Cyborg">Cyborg</option>
   <option value="Flatly">Flatly</option>
   <option value="Journal">Journal</option>
   <option value="Readable">Readable</option>
   <option value="Simplex">Simplex</option>
   <option value="Slate">Slate</option>
   <option value="Spacelab">Spacelab</option>
   <option value="United">United</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="mclick" value="click" />
```

JS:

```
// General Form Submit
$(function () {
    $('.error').hide();
    $("#mclick").click(function () {
        // validate and process form here  
        var theme = $("#site_theme").val();
        alert(theme);
    });
});
```